# How to set a defaultValue on optionGroups and/or select Fields in Magnolia CMS with Blossom?

Tags: magnolia

Setting a `defaultValue` is not working for `select`-fields nor for `optionGroup`-fields in Magnolia CMS with Blossom.

```java
@TabFactory("pages.properties.label")
public void pageProperties(UiConfig cfg, TabBuilder tab) {

    List<String> targetGroup = new ArrayList<>();
    targetGroup.add("Group A");
    targetGroup.add("Group B");

    List<String> menuTeaser = new ArrayList<>();
    menuTeaser.add("Teaser A");
    menuTeaser.add("Teaser B");

    tab.fields(
        cfg.fields.text("pageTitle").label("pages.properties.pageTitle.label").i18n()
            .description("pages.properties.pageTitle.description").i18n()
            .defaultValue("any value").i18n()   // works!
            .requiredErrorMessage("pages.properties.pageTitle.requiredErrorMessage").i18n()
            .required(),

        cfg.fields.select("targetGroup").label("pages.properties.targetGroup.label").i18n()
            .description("pages.properties.targetGroup.description").i18n()
            .options(targetGroup)
            .defaultValue(targetGroup.get(0)).i18n(),      // doesn't work!

        cfg.fields.optionGroup("menuTeaser").label("pages.properties.menuTeaser.label").i18n()
            .description("pages.properties.menuTeaser.description").i18n()
            .options(menuTeaser).i18n()
            .defaultValue(menuTeaser.get(0)).i18n()     // doesn't work!
            .required(),
    );
}
```

The interesting thing is, it works for `text`-fields.

How can this be accomplished for other field types?

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is set `selected=true` on the option that you want to have selected by default in the select. That's in normal Magnolia code. In case of Blossom and `TabBuilder`, it unfortunately allows you to set options as String only instead of exposing/allowing whole `SelectOption` to be passed in.
You would need to extend `TabBuilder` to create your own and overload `addSelect` method. Existing one looks like:

```
    public DialogSelect addSelect(String name, String label, String description, Collection<String> options) {
    try {
        DialogSelect select = DialogFactory.getDialogSelectInstance(
                context.getRequest(),
                context.getResponse(),
                context.getWebsiteNode(),
                null);
        select.setName(name);
        select.setLabel(label);
        select.setDescription(description);
        for (String option : options) {
            select.addOption(new SelectOption(option, option));
        }
        tab.addSub(select);
        return select;
    } catch (RepositoryException e) {
        throw new RuntimeRepositoryException(e);
    }
}
```

In yours you would want to pass in `Collection` of `SelectOption` items. To mark item as being selected, you simply call `mySelectOption.setSelected(true)`.

Alternatively you might want to contribute your overloaded code as a patch into Blossom itself.

HTH,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your suggestion running in a simple way. Thank you very much, none the less.

Eventually i solved the issue like this:

```
@TabFactory("pages.properties.label")
public void pageProperties(UiConfig cfg, TabBuilder tab) {

    List<String> targetGroup = new ArrayList<>();
    targetGroup.add(new OptionBuilder().value("Group A").label("Group A").selected());
    targetGroup.add(new OptionBuilder().value("Group B").label("Group B").selected());

    List<String> menuTeaser = new ArrayList<>();
    menuTeaser.add(new OptionBuilder().value("Group A").label("Teaser A").selected());
    menuTeaser.add(new OptionBuilder().value("Group A").label("Teaser B").selected());

    tab.fields(
        cfg.fields.text("pageTitle").label("pages.properties.pageTitle.label").i18n()
            .description("pages.properties.pageTitle.description").i18n()
            .defaultValue("any value").i18n()   // works!
            .requiredErrorMessage("pages.properties.pageTitle.requiredErrorMessage").i18n()
            .required(),

        cfg.fields.select("targetGroup").label("pages.properties.targetGroup.label").i18n()
            .description("pages.properties.targetGroup.description").i18n()
            .options(targetGroup.toArray(new OptionBuilder[targetGroup.size()])).i18n(),

        cfg.fields.optionGroup("menuTeaser").label("pages.properties.menuTeaser.label").i18n()
            .description("pages.properties.menuTeaser.description").i18n()
            .options(menuTeaser.toArray(new OptionBuilder[menuTeaser.size()])).i18n()
            .required(),
    );
}
```